# Is it possible to use MicroSD socket as a generic expansion card slot?

Tags: sd-card, hardware

Considering that I have:

- Android phone with MicroSD slot (non-rooted)
- A microcontroller with SDIO & SPI interfaces support

Is it possible for an app which is running on non-rooted device to establish a link (i.e. send arbitrary data in two ways) with a microcontroller?

Comment: No. In the root context maybe,  but you would have to write all the code and kernel drivers yourself, Android just isn't designed to use a microSD slot that way. I left this as a comment as I can't quote a source.

Comment: No, the SD card interface is very high-level, and only works for block filesystems. And even if it weren't, there's no way for a userspace app to talk directly to the card anyway.